# How do setMaxHealth to custom EntitySkeleton?

Tags: java, entity, minecraft, bukkit

I want to create a custom Skeleton that has a name, more health and holds other custom items.
I can add a name and `setHealth()`, but I can't `setMaxHealth()` and also setting items and armor just won't work.

Thanks for helping, here is my code:

```
Player p = (Player) sender;
WorldServer world = ((CraftWorld)p.getWorld()).getHandle();
Location loc = p.getLocation();

if (args.length > 0) {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("define")) {
                //get worldedit selection
                if (getWorldEdit().getSelection(p) == null) {
                    p.sendMessage(title + "Please select a region with WorldEdit");
                    return false;
                }
                s = getWorldEdit().getSelection(p);
                Location min = s.getMinimumPoint();
                Location max = s.getMaximumPoint();

                //boss mob creation
                EntitySkeleton boss = new EntitySkeleton(world);
                boss.setHealth(400);
                boss.setCustomName("§4§lDAFT BOSS");
                boss.setCustomNameVisible(true);

                ItemStack weapon = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
                weapon.setDurability((short) 0);
                weapon.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 5);
                weapon.addUnsafeEnchantment(Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 2);



                boss.setLocation(max);
                world.addEntity(boss);


            }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using NMS if at all possible (which I think is the case here).

Answer (score 2):

That can be obtained using the Attributable interface, as said in [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/setting-a-entitys-maximum-health.203214/) thread from Spigot.

---

Example:

For 1.9 and over:

```
Entity boss;
Attributable bossAttributable = (Attributable) boss;
AttributeInstance ai = bossAttributable.getAttribute(Attribute.GENERIC_MAX_HEALTH);
ai.setValue(400.0);
```

For 1.8.8 and lower, this must be done another way:

```
Entity boss;
Damageable bossDamageable = (Damageable) boss;
bossDamageable.setMaxHealth(400.0);
```

Comment: Attributable doesn't exist in 1.8.8 version. I can't figure out the Damageable either :(

Comment: You might need to set the entity's health accordingly, or else you'll get a 20 health skeleton with 400 max health, but not healed

Comment: It gives me this "INTERNAL ERROR" in server console:Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.EntitySkeleton cannot be cast to org.bukkit.entity.Damageable
 at me.sensonic.dcboss.Main.onCommand(Main.java:77) ~[?:?]
 at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]

Comment: There's no such thing such as EntitySkeleton in Bukkit. You're probably using CraftBukkit as your main library, and you shouldn't do it! Use normal Entity with `EntityType.Skeleton` instead

Comment: By normal i mean Bukkit's implementation

Comment: I think it's working, how would i get this Entity to spawn? Because world.addEntity(boss); only works for net.minecraft and not for org.bukkit.entity

Comment: Use [world.spawn](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/World.html#spawn(org.bukkit.Location,%20java.lang.Class,%20org.bukkit.util.Consumer))

Comment: Just replace "EntitySkeleton" with "Skeleton", as @Kerooker said. To initialize it, cast "world.spawnEntity(loc, EntityType.SKELETON)" to Skeleton.

Comment: When doing this it says: Skeleton is abstract, cannot be instantiated.

Comment: That's right, you're not instantiating it, you're spawning it using bukkit. AKA don't use `new Skeleton`